# Can a static constexpr member variable refer to its own address?

Tags: c++, scope, initialization, language-lawyer, constexpr

I've recently wanted to write code like this:

```
struct FunnyBusiness {
    static constexpr const void *IDENTITY = (const void *)&IDENTITY;
};
```

However, GCC (10.2) rejects this code ("IDENTITY was not declared in this scope") while Clang (11.0) compiles it just fine.

Is it legal for the initializer of a `static constexpr` member variable to take the address of the member variable itself?

Comment: It's nothing to do with `constexpr`.  gcc won't compile this either: `struct FunnyBusiness { inline static void *IDENTITY = &IDENTITY; };`, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/7dALAZIaJ39JYfA1